# XSS on javascript output in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xss

I have a page which takes a querystring parameter and outputs it as a javascript variable. This variable will be used as a parameter to navigate to page.

Will only `JSEncode` on the querystring parameter prevent XSS?

Input:

```
www.foo.com?t=abc<script>alert('hello xss')</script>
```

I want to emit this t value as a js var

```
var qs = Request.QueryString["t"].jsencode();
```

Comment: Please don't add "asp.net c#" to your title. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the AntiXSS class in the [Microsoft Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/). It has a host of useful methods for sanitizing input, including one to do exactly what you want: JavaScriptEncode.

Answer (score 0):

Side note in addition to properly encoding query string for JavaScript variable you should check if redirect actually allowed by your application logic. I.e. you may also want to block something like `www.foo.com?t=http://very.evil.com/dark.side` completely and flat out fail page rendering (unless you actually expect your page to do redirects to random other sites).

Answer (score 0):

You want to tackle this in two parts. Firstly, validate untrusted input against a white-list so in this case, you want to ensure that "t" is indeed a valid URL:

```
var sourceUri = Request.QueryString["t"];
if (!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(sourceUri, UriKind.Absolute))
{
  // Not a valid URI - bail out
}
```

Secondly, you should output encode for JavaScript. Your best way to do this is to grab [AntiXSS](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) and implement the following:

```
var encodedString = Encoder.JavaScriptEncode(sourceUri);
```

For more reading, try [OWASP Top 10 for .NET developers part 2: Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/05/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-2.html).